# Relationship between KL divergence, JS divergence, and MMD?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, distance-functions, kullback-leibler

What kind of relationship is there between the KL (Kullback-Leibler) divergence, JS (Jensen-Shannon) divergence, and MMD (maximum mean discrepancy)?

I know that they all share a global minimum at $P=Q$ and that the JS divergence can be defined using two KL divergences.
Are there any other known clear relationship among these three?

Comment: how can i use scipy to get the generator of a probability distribution with min KL divergence in python?